# Using Trait in Laravel Blade(Component)

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I try to use trait in laravel blade, but didn't work.

This is trait

```
namespace App\Repositories;

trait Residence
{
    public $country=['USA','Japan','Italy'];

    public $building=['duplex','condominium'];
}
```

I try to use in my blade like this:

```
@inject('Residence', 'App\Repositories\Residence')

@foreach($Residence->country as $country)
    {{$country}}
@endforeach

@foreach($Residence->building as $building)
    {{$building}}
@endforeach
```

But I get `Target [App\Repositories\Residence] is not instantiable.` error, any suggestion?(I'm using laravel 5.7)

Comment: A trait is supposed to be used by a Class, i dont know why you try to load it in blade ..

Comment: Well the reason I do this, is because there are variables in the trait and I need to inject into a blade(as a component)

Comment: Since trait won't work,so I have to build another class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thank you @Louis R remind that "A trait is supposed to be used by a Class"

So I use the trait in a class, and inject into the blade, it works!

This is trait.

```
namespace App\Repositories;

trait Residence
{
    public $country=['USA','Japan','Italy'];

    public $building=['duplex','condominium'];
}
```

This is a class use the trait.

```
namespace App\Repositories;

Class ResidenceClassForBlade
{
    use Residence;
}
```

This is blade:

```
@inject('Residence', 'App\Repositories\ResidenceClassForBlade')

@foreach($Residence->country as $country)
    {{$country}}
@endforeach

@foreach($Residence->building as $building)
    {{$building}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Do you render this view via some class?

Comment: No. This is a component blade, which will call by other blade like this: @component(the-blade-which-inject-a-class)

Comment: So, the parent blade is rendered via class. Right?

Comment: Yes, the parent blade is rendered via class, and there are many blades call this component as well.

Comment: So, parent class can use this trait `Residence` and you can pass parent class object in the view. This way you also have trait variables inside your view.

Comment: Yes,indeed, but there are more than one view include the component, so every class need to use the trait and pass data to view. It duplicate codes, so that’s why I tried to inject trait into the component blade in the beginning.

Comment: In that case, you can make a base Controller class and add this trait into it and make every controller class extend(inherit) that class. This will avoid you some manual injection.

Comment: This is a great idea. Btw, does inject into a blade not good? Are there any incident may happen?

Comment: Base on the BaseController idea, I refactor like this: a class use the trait, and then I inject into the blade, and it works! And it's better than I change the trait to a class.